# How to send non RDD vector to master in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am constructing a Map at the workers. This Map will be different in each worker because the data records available in the each worker will be different. How can I send this Map back to master so I can take the union of the elements?

Comment: I think you need to put up a little more detail than that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Spark you can retrieve all elements of your RDD at your master by calling `rdd.collect()`